# Sample Code to Call Odata Service from Java for onprem SAP

Tags: java, odata, sap-cloud-sdk

```
    /**
 * Calls {@code GET API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder} through
 * {@link FluentHelperRead} to get the SalesOrder events expanded to sales
 * order items and filtered by {@code keys} list
 *
 * @param keys
 *          the list of sales orders IDs to be fetched
 * @return the list of sales orders or an empty list if {@code keys} is empty
 *
 * @throws ODataException
 *           in case the request was not successful
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *           in case {@code keys} is null
 *
 * @see //ProcessSalesOrderService#getAllSalesOrder()
 * @see <a href=
 *    "https://api.sap.com/shell/discover/contentpackage/SAPS4HANACloud/api/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV?resource=A_SalesOrder&operation=get_A_SalesOrder">SAP
 *    API Business Hub</a> for details of
 *    {@code GET API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder} endpoint
 */
public List<SalesOrderHeader> getByKeys(@NonNull Collection<String> keys) throws IllegalArgumentException, ODataException {
    if (keys.size() == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    
    
    // create OData $filter with all keys 
    final ExpressionFluentHelper<SalesOrderHeader> filter = keys.stream()
            .map(key -> SalesOrderHeader.SALES_ORDER.eq(key))
            .reduce(ExpressionFluentHelper::or)
            .get();

    try {
        HttpDestinationProperties destinationprop = null;
        return salesOrderService.getAllSalesOrder()
            .select(SalesOrderHeader.ALL_FIELDS, SalesOrderHeader.TO_ITEM)
            .filter(filter)
            .execute(destinationprop );
    } catch (com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I found the above sample code but since I am new to SAP and my system is an OnPrem version deployed on AWS. I am not sure how to pass the HttpDestinationProperties destinationprop
Further that method seems to be deprecated.
I am looking for some sample code to call the Sales order Odata Service using the code I generated using the instructions provided.
I generated the code using a maven plugin. https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java I am using the odata V2 Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would use the SAP BTP Cloud Foundry [Destination Service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/7e306250e08340f89d6c103e28840f30.html) and [Connectivity Service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/313b215066a8400db461b311e01bd99b.html). Make sure to also have a [Cloud Connector](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e6c7616abb5710148cfcf3e75d96d596.html) connected to your sub-account, it will act as reverse-proxy to the On-Premise system. You bind the `destination` service (e.g. plan `lite`) as well as the `connectivity` service (e.g. plan `lite`) to your application.

Once the prerequisites are met, you can use the [SAP Cloud SDK code to resolve destinations](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-destination-service):

```java
// General API usage:
Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("my-destination");

// Cast to HTTP destination:
HttpDestination httpDestination = destination.asHttp(); 

// Apply dedicated ERP logic for SAP S/4HANA
HttpDestination erpHttpDestination = httpDestination.decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
```

(Of course you can boil it down to a one-liner.)

The OData call itself can be called like the following without try-catch:

```java
return salesOrderService.getAllSalesOrder()
  .select(SalesOrderHeader.ALL_FIELDS, SalesOrderHeader.TO_ITEM)
  .filter(filter)
  .executeRequest( erpHttpDestination );
```

That's it!

PS.: If you want to define your destination in static code, that would be possible with the `DefaultErpHttpDestination.builder("http://your-proxy-host:44300")` API. However this is obviously not best-practice.

Comment: I was trying to connect to the Odata Service from my desktop. I am able to get to the URL from my desktop without issues so I should be able to get to it without using SAP BTP cloud foundry I assume?

Comment: I assume your desktop is connected to a company network / proxy. The SAP BTP Cloud Foundry is **not** connected to your company network without _Cloud Connector_